# CSS3 Font Embedding doesn't work at Iphone OS3.0 safari?

Tags: iphone, css

I tried to embed font at web pages. I can see the font rendering properly at latest non-IE browsers, but when I tried with Iphone Safari Browser, it doesn't render. I want to know whether Iphone Safari supports font embedding. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

They work in SVG format. Use the fontsquirrel.com generator to make the SVG version.

Comment: When embedding your fonts, make sure you read through this article: http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/ - fontsquirrel already implements it, but it's worth making sure you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd noticed the same thing, but in truth you can get it to work but with SVG fonts. See this article: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/ for a method for converting web fonts into enough formats to be truly cross-platform.